# How do you render the front page of a plone site in python?

Tags: python, plone, zope

The following browser view *should* return the content of the front page of the first Plone Site in it's context. However, I can not seem to obtain an object which is able to render html content.

```
from Products.Five import BrowserView
from zope.component import getMultiAdapter

class RenderFirst (BrowserView):
    def __call__ (self):

        def findPlones (context):
            plones = context.objectValues("Plone Site")
            folders = context.objectValues("Folder")
            folders = set(folders).difference(set(plones))
            for folder in folders:
                plones += findPlones(folder)
            return plones

        plones = findPlones(context)


        if len(plones):
            default_page = plones[0].getDefaultPage()
            content = plones[0].unrestrictedTraverse (default_page)
            view = getMultiAdapter ((content, self.request))
            return view()

        else:
            return "no plone"
```

The previous code when run tells me that the object view is not callable.

`plones[0]` is a Plone Site object and when called produces a `KeyError` for `folder_listing`
if I call the `content` object I get an `AttributeError` for `document_view`

There are lots of combinations here, of calling different adapters of different objects. Haven't yet found the right object which can render the page. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Some code comments: Why traverse through all folders when you only need the first one found? Also, context.objectValues("Folder") will *never* return a Plone site, so your "set(folders).difference(set(plones))" line is redundant.

Comment: What does it tell you that `view` *is*? Real error messages are helpful. Is it a Document?  Obviously if it says "None type object is not callable", the answer is trivial...

Comment: @Martijn, thanks for the feedback - my intention was to treat each Plone instance found, so I could [health check](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pretaweb.healthcheck) them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.subrequest.

Answer (score 2):

When I try this in a pdb a simple `plones[0]()` works fine.

Comment: Or you can do view.__of__(content)() I believe.